# Excel - insert cell ending with a certain condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I create a general formula to filter a range based on certain criteria?

Lets say I have the following items in column A:

```
45c-36
45c-37
45c-38
485
645b-15
645b-16
954r
```

From this I only want to see cells that ends with `37`, `15` and all cells without `-` (like `485` and `954r`).

So I will end up with only the below in one column:

```
45c-37
485
645b-15
954r
```

I have tried:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="37";A1;"")
```

However, it doesn't really seem to work out with values without -, and it also becomes very complicated.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1, 2) = "37", RIGHT(A1, 2) = "15", NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-", A1)))), A1, "")
```